# FileNotFoundException при загрузке фотографии из галереи

Tags: java, android, fileupload, asynchttpclient

Никак не могу понять, как загрузить картинку из галереи корректно.
Вылетает исключение, о том что такой файл не найден, когда кладу его в Request Params.
Пользуюсь вот этой библиотекой для запросов: [ссылка](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

Вот код:

```
public void onClickImageViewAvatar(View view) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {

                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                File file = new File(imageUri.toString());

                String URL = "http://*****";
                RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
                requestParams.put("photo", file);// ошибка здесь
                requestParams.put("token",user.getToken());
                requestParams.put("user_id", user.getUser_id());

                client.post(URL, requestParams, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i("fg", "change avatar " + response.toString());
                        try {
                            String status = response.getString("status");
                            if (Objects.equals(status, STATUS_FAIL)) {


                            } else if (Objects.equals(status, STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
                                imageViewAvatar.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                });



            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(ProfileSettings.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ProfileSettings.this, "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Вывод при исключении:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.put(RequestParams.java:285)
    at com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.put(RequestParams.java:271)
    at com.example.uncolor.aroundme.ProfileSettings.onActivityResult(ProfileSettings.java:281)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6295)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3929)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3976)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1578)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5747)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Разрешение на чтение external storage есть?

Comment: Да,  есть и на запись и на чтение в манифесте

Comment: Покажите `uri` файла

Comment: А в рантайме у пользователя Вы эти разрешения запрашиваете?

Comment: Нет, не запрашиваю

Comment: uri начинается с "content://"(у меня сейчас нет доступа к компьютеру,  позже могу написать конкретно что выдает)