# Не загружается фотография из галереи (FileNotFoundExeption)

Tags: java, android, post, android-file

Не могу загрузить фотографию из галереи и отправить ее в post-запросе.
Прикладываю код:

```
public void onClickImageViewAvatar(View view) {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            File file = new File(imageUri.toString());

            String URL = "http://*****";
            RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
            requestParams.put("photo", file);// ошибка здесь
            requestParams.put("token",user.getToken());
            requestParams.put("user_id", user.getUser_id());

            client.post(URL, requestParams, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                    Log.i("fg", "change avatar " + response.toString());
                    try {
                        String status = response.getString("status");
                        if (Objects.equals(status, STATUS_FAIL)) {


                        } else if (Objects.equals(status, STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
                            imageViewAvatar.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(ProfileSettings.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(ProfileSettings.this, "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.put(RequestParams.java:285)
    at com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.put(RequestParams.java:247)
    at com.example.uncolor.aroundme.ProfileSettings.onActivityResult(ProfileSettings.java:302)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6295)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3929)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3976)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1578)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5747)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Поищите в логах по слову `denied`.

Comment: И еще, чем вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690122/filenotfoundexception-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B80) вопрос отличается от текущего?

Comment: Ничем,  мне на него так и не ответили,  но проблема осталась

Comment: Попробуйте соответствующие пермишены запросить в рантайме.

Comment: Можно пример, пожалуйста

Comment: Пример чего Вам нужен?

Comment: Вот этого пермишена, и где конкретно его нужно вставить

Comment: В [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) есть пример.

Comment: Я все равно не понимаю, в манифесте все прописано
И все равно какие то проблемы с этим

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62815/discussion-between---and-post-zeew).

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с материалом, который приведен по ссылке.

Comment: У меня картинка загружается в imageView
Почему то  RequestParams его не воспринимает

Comment: Я пользуюсь  Async-http-client от   loopj

Comment: попробуйте так
File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос: [Как получить путь к файлу из URI?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413401/11515)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возвращенный `Uri` не всегда является `File`. Вам нужно получить абсолютный путь до выбранного изображения с помощью `ContentResolver`:

```
 final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
 Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(imageUri,null,null,null,null);
 if (c.moveToNext()) {
    String path = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
    File file = new File(path);
    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
    requestParams.put("photo", file);// ошибки уже нет
 }

 c.close(); // не забудьте курсор закрыть
```